# How to reset Windows10, remove Ubuntu from dual boot, and change boot mode to UEFI?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, uefi

I have Windows10 + Ubuntu in Legacy Boot Mode. 
I would like to do the following things:

1. **Remove Ubuntu** from dual boot, so my ONLY OS will be Windows.
2. **Delete all** my files and software, really reset my laptop to a "brand new" Windows10 (I want the boot mode to **change to UEFI!**).
3. I hope that it'll solve the problem (changing to UEFI), so I can install Windows11.

Thanks! (Don't worry, I'm not reseting my laptop only becasue of Windows11)

<If it's not the right forum to ask that kind of question, forgive me. Where is the right forum?>

Comment: That will work. Make sure you have TPMv2, secure boot, and add at least an 8th generation CPU

Comment: @John Glad to here it'll work. How do I do all those steps? I don't know any of it :(

Comment: After verifying @John pre-reqs.. 1) create windows 10 boot with "media creation tool" provided by microsoft.  2)boot into uefi firmware (aka bios) and hunt down drive wipe utility 3) wipe drive 4) boot from usb media made from media creation tool and reinstall.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Can you tell me if those links are good? 1) https://www.mychoicesoftware.com/pages/support-windows-10-installation-via-bootable-media 2) I didn't find a link to tell me how to do it 3) https://www.backblaze.com/blog/how-to-wipe-pc-ssd-or-hard-drive/ 4) https://www.acronis.com/en-us/blog/posts/usb-boot/

Comment: 1) Use the [windows media creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).  It will also download the ISO to your USB stick.  2)  Enter your firmware/bios on boot (every system is different) and HUNT for drive utilities.  Most UEFI firmware now contain a section to secure wipe the drive.  You will need to hunt, they don't want people clicking it on accident. 3) If you can't do this, you should be able to wipe it from the windows USB stick itself.. when you get the to partitioning, delete everything.  Then let windows lay it out.